# url assistance while web development using php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have categories saved in databse,
ex.

```
    Category 1
    Category 2
             .
             .
    Category 10
```

[image]

Now my menus are,

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/home/Category_page.php?id=1" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_page.php?id=2" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_page.php?id=3" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_page.php?id=4" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_page.php?id=5" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_page.php?id=6" >Category name</a></li>
<ul>
```

i wanted to do like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/home/Category_name" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_name" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_name" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_name" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_name" >Category name</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/Category_name" >Category name</a></li>
<ul>
```

category names will be different, in href only category name is given, in .htaccess i can redirect to another page,like

> Rule in .htaccess:-

```
 RewriteRule ^home/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /details.php/$1.php
```

Here on details page should i check category name in database to fetch details?

or

what are the another options? 
I don't want category id in url.

Comment: Yes to the first, it's about your only option if you want to omit the id from the url (do remember to set a UNIQUE index on the category name in your database to avoid clashes).

Comment: @Wrikken category id will be unique !

Comment: And if you want to make the _category name_ the only part of the url that won't make a lick of difference: then _category name_ _MUST_ be unique if you want to omit the id.

Comment: Wrikken is correct; the category name must definitely be unique.  You said you do not want to handle page selection by category ID with your URL, you're looking up by category name.  If you have two categories with the same name and the name is used in the URL, *how do you think you'll ever get to the second page?*  I'll save you time: you won't.  Either you **have** to use unique category names, or you **have** to use the category ID in the URL some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a finite number of categories and they don't change very often you could use `RewriteMap` to map the names in the pretty handled URLs to the versions with Ids.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Otherwise you could add a lookup in the database (either a table joined to the category table or a new column in your category table) with a unique column containing the URL friendly category name that you want.